# how to do login and get analytics event data using php

Tags: php, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I need google analytics event data with user login. menas i need specific user logged in into google account event data now i am using a script i am able to login in to google account and able to get google Oauth token also but when i  am integrating this script to the google analytics event data code it is not working properly.

Here is my script currently i am using for login into google account

```
    include_once("config.php");
    include_once("includes/functions.php");

    //print_r($_GET);die;

    if(isset($_REQUEST['code'])){
        $gClient->authenticate();
        $_SESSION['token'] = $gClient->getAccessToken();
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirectUrl, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
        $gClient->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
    }

    if ($gClient->getAccessToken()) {
        $userProfile = $google_oauthV2->userinfo->get();
        //DB Insert
        $gUser = new Users();
        $gUser->checkUser('google',$userProfile['id'],$userProfile['given_name'],$userProfile['family_name'],$userProfile['email'],$userProfile['gender'],$userProfile['locale'],$userProfile['link'],$userProfile['picture']);
        $_SESSION['google_data'] = $userProfile; // Storing Google User Data in Session
        header("location: account.php");
        $_SESSION['token'] = $gClient->getAccessToken();
    } else {
        $authUrl = $gClient->createAuthUrl();
    }

    if(isset($authUrl)) {
        echo '';
    } else {
        echo 'Logout';
    }
```

and it is working fine for me i need google analytics event data now so pls tell me how i can get data now.

Thanks.

Comment: The Google Analytics API team has a tutorial for that https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-php